# SQL: How to use DISTINCT on a foreign key without using it in an aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql

So I want to find the average amount everyone who purchased flowers, earns. However, I need to account for duplicates, because some people may have purchased flowers multiple times, and that would mess up the average.

But when I put `DISTINCT sales.customerid` it wants me to put it in an aggregate function, but when I do that, it separates the averages. It doesn't put it into one average.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sales.customerid, AVG(moneyearned) AS averageearned
FROM customer,  sales
WHERE customer.customerid = sales.customerid 
AND (purchaseflower = TRUE);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3):

You might use `group by` instead of `DISTINCT`

By the Way,`INNER JOIN` is better than `CROSS JOIN` on this case.

```
SELECT customer.CustomerID, AVG(moneyearned) AS averageearned
FROM customer INNER JOIN sales
ON customer.CustomerID = sales.customerid 
WHERE purchaseflower = TRUE
GROUP BY customer.CustomerID;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/149ee2/2)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this but I get the same result, each of the customer ID's next to their earned money. How do I make it display only the average of all money earned?

Comment: You didn't need to  group by  `sales.customerid`, If you want to display average of all money.
Could you give me mock data for tables `sales` and `customer`

Comment: https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/embeddedchart/37b3b98c-1148-4fab-b81a-9c35339e3650

Comment: @cluelessdatabase I edited my answer,and 
I try to do some mock data with table schema you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY clause instead of Distinct this will group all duplicate customers.

```
SELECT sales.customerid, AVG(moneyearned) AS averageearned
FROM customer,  sales
WHERE customer.customerid = sales.customerid 
AND (purchaseflower = TRUE)
GROUP BY sales.customerid;
```

But remember all attributes in SELECT which are not in aggregated function should be present inside GROUP BY clause.